# Are there pet safe ways to eliminate static in pet fur beyond a humidifier (especially in rabbits)?

Tags: safety, rabbits, grooming

I have 2 rabbits, and in the winter they become so full of static that I can't even pet them without giving/receiving a static shock.

Using a humidifier helps a great deal. Yet, even with relative humidity at 50%, static shocks begin after just a few strokes across their back.

While this isn't surprising as rabbit hair is one of the most positively charged natural substances on Earth, it's quite annoying as the discharge is usually to the rabbits' ears or nose, or to my face.  I'd love to find another way to combat it that won't harm my rabbits.

Are there any natural and safe-to-eat anti-static treatments?

Am I correct to assume that dryer sheets, diluted fabric softener and/or anti-static salon products are too toxic to use on a pet?

Comment: I have 5 rabbits, one of which spends an hour or two laying in bed with me getting petted while I read.  I have never experienced this static build up and shock.  I live in PA and the humidity in the house runs 60 to 70%.  My guess is that there is something environmental in your clothing, shoes or furniture that is causing this.  Can you expand more on possible environmental triggers?

Comment: What breed of rabbits?  Or more appropriately what fur type, Angora, Rex, normal Flyback, normal non-flyback.

Comment: @JamesJenkins it's probably because your humidity is above [recommended levels](http://www.homeenergyresourcemn.org/how_your_house_works/section_index.aspx?cat_1=752&cat_2=795&SelectCatID=795&CatId=795&ref=795:HYHW_LN) - I wish I could turn mine up that high, but fear black mold.

Comment: @Chad both are lionhead, one is closer to angora, the other is closer to rex

Comment: During this cold dry spell, the humidity has been running about 40% still no issues with static.  All of my bunnies have short hair.

Comment: @JamesJenkins my problems start when the humidity drops below 35 because the humidifier runs out of water.  When I bring the humidity back up it doesn't always help.  Further, it's 8 degrees F out right now so I shouldn't have my humidity set to over 30, but have left it on and it'a at about 36 and the buns mostly free of static unless I pet them for more than 5 min.

Comment: Lionhead would count as angora type.  You can try combing a small amount of baby powdeer(talc based) throught their mane.  Its not great for the fur but if these are just pets not show it will be fine.

Comment: Update, we did have a few issues with static during the driest periods.  Given the what we experienced this winter and your answer, I am guessing it is not the humidity of the air but of the humidity of the hair of the pet that causes the static (See that I skipped the word play *hair of the hare*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently saw [this video](http://rabbit.org/do-rabbits-shed/) on rabbit.org and at the end, she recommends moistening your hands with water during the grooming process as a way to prevent hair from flying everywhere / clean up the hair that is everywhere.  Upon trying this, I noticed it also helped considerably with static issues, and seemed to keep the rabbit relatively static free for hours after.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with rabbits, but if I was having this problem with one of my cats I'd try supplementing their diet with some type of oil (Omega 3 or Omega 6 come to mind) to get more moisture into their fur.

(Okay, I did once apply shea butter to one of the cats to try to moisturize her skin. Not recommended!)

Comment: Adding oils or any substance that you are not sure about to a rabbits diet is very dangerous.  Rabbit GI tract is a delicate balance that can be upset and have fatal consequenses.