# How can I keep my pet from being full of static?

Tags: cats, health

I love cuddling with my cat. Lately we have had our nightly cuddle and pet, and I have noticed that he is very staticky, creating lots of bright static sparks every time I pet his fur.

Is there anything I can do to stop him being a static electricity machine? I know my apartment is somewhat dry because of the heaters I have going, would that be part of the problem?

How can I stop my cat from being so shocking when I pet him?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there pet safe ways to eliminate static in pet fur beyond a humidifier? (especially in rabbits)](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1809)

Comment: Simplest way is a slightly damp towel to carry off the charge.

Answer (score 4):

for my dog we use a moisturizing anti-static spray for the dry winter months. It worked pretty well. Here's an example product that is recommended for dogs and cats. [http://www.amazon.com/Coat-Handler-Anti-Static-Detangler-Spray/dp/B002PNITHQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002PNITHQ). I didn't use that one but i'm sure any pet store clerk would be able to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

An anti-static pet spray, and you can hang moist rags on or near the heaters, that'll moisten the air. Or moisten the air in any other way, for example, with commercial air humidifiers, or you can put a pot of water to boil and let it boil for a while.

Comment: I keep a few bowls of water on the radiators all winter.  It not only reduces static, it makes the place feel subjectively warmer.